# Adblock Plus blocks css on localhost

Tags: html, css, localhost, ads, adblock

I wrote a web-application called "adsync"
Now my AdBlock Plus obviously doesn't like the name (maybe it sounds too much like "advertising"...) and blocks the .css and all the images.

It works perfectly when I deactivate AdBlock, but can I fix that problem without turning it off?

Comment: Well, you could configure your AdBlock to allow anything on localhost, but seeing as the name triggers blocking, I'd recommend you rename it.

Comment: I don't want to rename it because it's the name of my application.
How do I allow anything on localhost?
Please add it as an answer. :)

Comment: Well, this has little to do with programming, so I doubt it's an appropriate question for SO. Also: 1) Your css file doesn't need to have the same name as your app. 2) Having a local file that triggers AdBlock will most likely trigger when published live (your visitors with adblock will have the same issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AdBlock also block html elements with css **Class** or **ID** like (ads-block, advertising , ads, ... ). It is better don't use ads words for files, CSS class or id and other html attributes in your app :)